# Access html drag and drop with python

Tags: python, html, classification

I have found a very nice algorithm for image classification (https://everypixel.com/aesthetics) and was wondering if its possible to upload image files to the webpage with python. They are using a drag and drop system for the image files. Because the algorithm tags those uploaded pictures, the possibility of automatic upload would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Python is just a language and not a framework. This means it is not sufficient to be a web server(something that will accept a request and respond to it).
So you need to use a server like [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to accept the request and implement your algorithm there.To attach a file you need to implement a frontend as well.